# Calculus of variations

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, calculus-of-variations, economics

I have the following question and I wasn't sure if I can apply the calculus of variations to it. The control function is $Q$.

$$\max \int_0^1 t Q(t) dt$$

subject to:

1. $Q$ is weakly increasing
2. $Q(0) \geq 0$
3. $Q(1) \leq 1$
4. $2∫_s^1 Q(t)dt≤1−s^2$
5. $∫_0^1tQ′(t)(1−t)dt≤C$

My main question is if I can apply the Calculus of Variations to this problem and if so, then the consequence that I expect to derive is that either condition 1 or 4 must bind almost everywhere.

NB. I would like to allow that Q is only piecewise continuous. It is already required to be weakly and can range at most from 0 to 1.

Comment: Given that you allow jump discontinuities to $Q$, is $Q'$ in the integral **5** to be intended as **A)** a distributional derivative, so that the integral is $-\int_0^1Q(t)(1-2t)dt$, or **B)** is it the a.e. derivative of the increasing function $Q$ (so that a step function would give $Q'=0$, and a null integral) ?

Comment: Dear Pietro, I've thought about it, and I intended the former. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: So for $C\ge0$ there is the trivial constant maximizer $Q=1/2$ right?

Comment: Hi Pietro, my mistake, I forgot a term in the optimizer. Regarding the sign of $C$, in the basic formulation, I take $C$ to be positive, but when we do the integration by parts that you rightly suggest, then $C$ updates and is now negative. Without the 5th condition, the ideal function would be $Q(t)=t$.